# Rename file using custom npm script

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I want to make a script for my angular2 project that renames `README.md` to `README_2.md`. I installed  `"renamer" : "0.6.1"` and made this script:

`"renameMd": "renamer --find js/README.md --replace js/README_2.md"` in `package.json`, but it doesn't work. It gives me this error: `No input files supplied`.  How can I fix it ?

PS: the file is located in the js folder.

Comment: @Pablo lol thanks :0 . But now it gives me this error: `No input files supplied`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`renamer` takes a last parameter to filter the files that need to be renamed.

`renamer --find README --replace README_2 js/README.md` should work.

If you are using Linux, you could also use `mv`: `mv js/README.md js/README_2.md` (`move` in Windows).